# Preventing Direct URL to views in angular + firebase web app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not an expert as I started working in firebase and angularjs a few weeks ago. I'm building a server based web application using firebase, nodejs(for server) and angularjs and I've a login scenario for my web application, Now I want to prevent direct URL access, after checking that a user is login or not. I want to redirect it to login page if user try to access via direct URL.
I tried using this but it doesn't seems to work.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
// User is signed in.
} else {
// No user is signed in.
}
});
```

Can some provide me a working example of preventing access to URLs using angularjs and firebase?
Thanks in Advances

Comment: That callback should fire when the page loads and detect whether the user is signed into Firebase Authentication. What doesn't work?

Comment: It's working now! I was having a code problem. :)